# Android NFC reading

Tags: android, nfc, intentfilter

Following the tutorial: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reading-nfc-tags-with-android--mobile-17278

I'm wondering if it is possible to only respond to NFC requests when the application is open AND is on the current activity that handles those events?

Currently I have in my manifest (inside the activity that responds):

```
<!-- NFC Reader -->
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

In the activity onCreate

```
// Responds to NFC Device Reader
 resolveIntent(getIntent());
```

And

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);
    resolveIntent(intent);
}


private void resolveIntent(Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
            || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
            || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {

        Parcelable tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

        processInformation(tag);

    }
}
```

The reson being I have an authentication process which is being bypassed as the application loads this activity directly.

Comment: What is happening? What's the behaviour with your current code that is not working as you'd like?

Comment: The activity is launched when a NFC chip is scanned. Instead, I only want the activity to collect the NFC data when it is open. If the app isn't open and isn't on this activity I don't want any response.

Comment: Then try to register that activity dynamically so it wont call every time. even if your application is not active. it will call only if your Activity is open use activity life cycle methods to handle that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the author of the tutorial. Simply remove the IntentFilter in the manifest and only implement the foreground dispatch. Then it should work that way.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you for the answer and the tutorial, very helpful.